# Is the metamorphosis of a caterpillar into a butterfly mentioned anywhere in Rabbinic literature?

Tags: sources-mekorot, animals, science, bugs

My late great grandfather was a torah scholar, but with all his learning, he never knew that a caterpillar metamorphoses into a butterfly. He was amazed when someone told him about the common phenomenon. 
My question is, is this metamorphosis ever mentioned in torah literature, be it Tanach, Chazal, Rishonim, or Acharonim?

Comment: See Malbim ([*Iyov* 27:18](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%99%22%D7%9D_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%95%D7%91_%D7%9B%D7%96#.D7.A4.D7.A1.D7.95.D7.A7_.D7.99.D7.97_.28.D7.9B.D7.9C_.D7.94.D7.A4.D7.A8.D7.A7.29.28.D7.9B.D7.9C_.D7.94.D7.A4.D7.A1.D7.95.D7.A7.29)) who interprets the verse as referring to the ephemeral nature of a Lepidoptera chrysalis.

Comment: @Fred, sounds like an answer; why not post it as such?

Comment: @msh210 I guess so, but I would feel more comfortable in posting an answer if I was prepared to include an analysis of traditional understandings of the עש/סס/אבזקא/דרנא, as well as a *halachic* discussion of the status of a caterpillar (whether it is considered *sheretz ha'of* and/or whether the status should be dependent on the fact that it has a flying form at a later stage). Oh well, I'll post it as is for now and hopefully someone will come along with a more thorough answer at some point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Iyov* ([27:18](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2727.htm#18)) discusses the ephemeral nature of a wicked person's success:

> בָּנָה כָעָשׁ בֵּיתוֹ וּכְסֻכָּה עָשָׂה נֹצֵר

Translation (Mechon-Mamre):

> He buildeth his house as a moth,<sup>1</sup> and as a booth which the keeper maketh.

The [Malbim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malbim) ([*Iyov*, ibid.](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%99%22%D7%9D_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%95%D7%91_%D7%9B%D7%96#.D7.A4.D7.A1.D7.95.D7.A7_.D7.99.D7.97_.28.D7.9B.D7.9C_.D7.94.D7.A4.D7.A8.D7.A7.29.28.D7.9B.D7.9C_.D7.94.D7.A4.D7.A1.D7.95.D7.A7.29)) interprets the verse as referring to the ephemeral nature of a Lepidoptera chrysalis:

> כמו שהעש בעת שמתעטף במעטפה שזה ביתו, ואחר שיוצא מן המעטפה את ביתו ישא רוח

Translation (mine):

> Just as the moth, when it wraps itself in the chrysalis that becomes its home, afterwards, when it emerges from the chrysalis, its home is blown away by the wind....

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Likely, the word עָשׁ in Biblical usage can apply to the entire order [Lepidoptera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepidoptera).</sub>

Comment: Thanks Fred. One comment: When the Malbim concludes ישא רוח, you assumed it refers to the house. I think it refers to the insect itself: the wind lifts it, meaning it can fly.

Comment: @Murex Interesting read, but then what do you do with the words "את ביתו"?